# LWJGL - Why will my floatbuffer not allocate directly?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am having difficulty getting LWJGL to accept my floatbuffer.

I am using LWJGL's methods to allocate a direct floatbuffer but it will still throw an exception for 'allocate direct.'

Two instance variables in the chunk class:

> private Floatbuffer buffer;
> private int vertCount;

After my vertex array is populated:

> buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertCount);
> buffer.put(vertArray);
> buffer.rewind();

A handle for the VBO is acquired by:

> vertID = VBOutil.createVBOID();
>
> public static int createVBOID()
> {
> IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
> GL15.glGenBuffers(buffer);
>
> ```
>   return buffer.get(0);
> ```
>
> }

The method I use to bind the buffer:

> public static void vertexBufferData(int id, FloatBuffer buffer)
> {
> GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
> GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
> }

My program flow is such that each frame a call is sent to vertexBufferData, and then to the following method:

> public static void render(int vertID, int numIndices)
> {
> GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertID);
>
> ```
>   GL11.glVertexPointer(3,  GL11.GL_FLOAT, 40, 0);  
>   GL11.glNormalPointer(GL11.GL_FLOAT, 40, 12);  
>   GL11.glColorPointer(4, GL11.GL_FLOAT,  40, 24);  
>     
>   GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS,  0, numIndices);  
>     
>   GL11.glPopMatrix();
> ```
>
> }

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while.

EDIT:
Here is the stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkDirect(BufferChecks.java:138)
> at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glBufferData(GL15.java:155)
> at lwjgl.VBOutil.vertexBufferData(VBOutil.java:27)
> at lwjgl.Chunk.bind(Chunk.java:35)
> at lwjgl.ChunkLoader.bind(ChunkLoader.java:81)
> at lwjgl.ChunkLoader.render(ChunkLoader.java:68)
> at lwjgl.Scene.update(Scene.java:19)
> at lwjgl.Main.gameLoop(Main.java:32)
> at lwjgl.Main.main(Main.java:17)

vertArray is an array of floats.

My chunk class is an abstraction for a terrain made of cubes along the simplex noise function. I construct 'blocks' and add them to a block arraylist if they are within a threshold to the noise surface. The vertice information is then taken from each block and added to a float arraylist. Once the size is known I put the vertice information into an array to be put into a float buffer by LWGL's utility method. Right now my chunkloader class only holds 1 chunk so that I may debug this problem. I plan on using separate VBO handles for each chunk since the chunkloader should not have more than 9 chunks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which line produces the exception? And please show us the stacktrace.

Comment: We need the error message, and stack trace.

Comment: Also what is 'vertArray' ?

Comment: @AnubianNoob I would highly guess it's a `float[]`, did you really have to ask?